# How can I retrieve the UID of each document retrieved from FireStore DB when I subscribe my service method (performing the query)?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am working on an Angular project retrieving data from Firebase **FireStore** database. It works fine but now I am finding problem trying to retrieve the documents UID. I will try to explain my situation in details.

Into my FireStore DB I have something like this:

[image]

So, as you can see, at the moment I only have a single collection named **calendar** containing some documents where each document represent an event on a calendar (but this detail is not so important now).

Into my Angular application I have a service class containing this method that simply perform a query to retrieve all the documents inside my **calendar** collection:

```
/**
* Return the list of all the work shift related to all the person in the calendar:
*/
getEvents(): Observable<any[]> {
    this.items = this.db.collection('calendar').valueChanges();

    return this.items;
}
```

So this method return an **Observable** of array on any objects.

Subscribing this **Observable** into my component I retrieve the list of documents stored into the **calendar** collection in FireStore.

I have done in this way (this is the code snippet into my component typescript file calling the previous service method):

```
this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(events => { this.events = events.map((event) => {

  //console.log("START: ", event.start);
  var date = event.start.toDate()
  var hour = date.getHours();

  var startDateAsString = this.fromDateToString(date);

  event.start = startDateAsString;

  if(hour === 7) {
    event['backgroundColor'] = 'red';
  }
  else if(hour === 15) {
    event['backgroundColor'] = 'green';
  }
  else if(hour === 23) {
    event['backgroundColor'] = 'black';
  }

  console.log("EVENT: ", event);

  return event;
})});
```

So as you can see I am subscribing the previous service method performing the query and I "iterate" on the query resultset using the **map()** operator building my **this.events** array. It works fine.

My problem is: in this context how can I retrieve the UID of each documents retrieved by Firebase in order to add this information to the returned **event** variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`valueChanges()` does not include the `id` for the documents it receives.  You need to use `snapshotChanges()` and then pipe the data to create an object.

I do something like this in my app

```js
this.db.collection('collectionName').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(snapshots => {
       return snapshots.map(s => {
        // if you log s here, you can look through the object
        // payload.doc.data() should be the same as what valueChanges returns
        // payload.doc.id will be the id
        // merge them into a new object
        return {...s.payload.doc.data(), id: s.payload.doc.id)}
     })
    }
);
```